# Release version much snappier than debug version

Tags: android, performance

I just launched my first Android app into alpha, and I noticed that the release version downloaded from the play store is much more responsive than the debug version.

I assume this means Android Studio is doing some optimization on the release version that it's not doing on the debug version. My question, if that's true, is does this indicate there are inefficiencies in my code I should be tracking down? Or should I just take this as an unanticipated benefit of publishing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A debug version of your app is meant to be optimized for that- even if that means adding extra logs (from the system or from you app), systems to catch errors, data tracking and management, everything you can access from the debug menu, and much more.

However, when a release apk is made, it doesn't need all those features (which make it easier on your life for making your app). Furthermore, there are speed-related optimizations that can be made to the app by the compiler, which stop you from normally debugging. Thus, it tends to be faster/more responsive- although the varying degrees of improvement depends on what your app is actually doing.

In regards to inefficiencies in your code, without knowing anything about your situation I can just say "it depends." Take note that this does **not** necessarily mean your code is inefficient- I just can't say for sure your code itself is inefficient or not.

By the way, this is normal practice- when debugging, a less optimized program is made for the sake of debugging. If you've ever dealt with C++ and the g++ compiler, it's like using the -g flag for, say, debugging with gdb yet using the -O3 flag for making a faster, smaller program.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you compile in debug mode, the compiler leaves in stuff which helps when debugging. When compiling in release mode, it makes optimizations which slow down the compile but make the app run faster.

Also if you use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) in your release version it will optimize the code to make it run faster.

Hope this helps!